# Cordova - InAppBrowser plugin not work with external Whitelist plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

In my project on Cordova I use InAppBrowser and Whitelist plugins.
Application show my content. And after click on link of site, it show in application. When user click "Back to application" application back to show my content.
When I use project with default settings of Whitelist all is ok. External URLs open in application with control button (back, forward etc) and button "Back to application". But I can not show in application video from youtube because I was not add domen "youtube" in whitelist.
Then I add domen "youtube" to whitelist:

```
<allow-navigation href="*youtube*" />
<allow-navigation href="*ytimg*" />
```

And then plugin InAppBrowser not work. URLs show, but not show control buttons and button "Back to application". And it is impossible to return to the application (when it compile for iOs)

How setup Whitelist for work with youtube and with InAppBrowser?
Or how show external sites in my application?

Please not say about iFrame!

This issue actually only for iOs!

По русски:
В приложении на кордове использую два плагина - whitelist и inappbrowser. Приложение показывает мой контент, а при клике по внешним ссылкам показывается внешний сайт прямо в окне приложения. При клике по кнопке "Назад в приложение" снова открывается мой контент. Когда использую настройки whitelist по-умолчанию, всё отлично. Внешние сайты показываются в приложении с панелью управления браузера (назад, вперед и тд) и кнопкой "Назад в приложение". Это делает InAppBrowser. Но не показывается видео с ютуба. Потому что доменн ютуба не добавлен в белый список. Добавляю его так:

```
<allow-navigation href="*youtube*" />
<allow-navigation href="*ytimg*" />
```

После этого видео показывается. Но перестает работать плагин InAppBrowser. Страницы внешних сайтов отображаются в приложении но без управляющих элементов браузера и без кнопки "Назад в приложение". И после компиляции на айфоны нет возможности вернуться к контенту приложения. Так как внешний сайт на всё окно приложения, и кнопки НАЗАД нет.

Можно ли как-то настроить whitelist чтобы и видео показывалось и работал плагин инаппбраузер?

Или может есть другой вариант показать внешние сайты в моем приложении?

iFrame не предлагать. Отпадает из-зи политик безопасности сайтов. Не отображаются.

Проблема актуальна только для iOs!

My system:
cordova 6.4.0
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
compile in xcode 7.2.1